# Whats wrong with my user input in C

Tags: c

I know python decently well, I've been trying to learn C for the past ~4 days. I found this code online edited it a tad bit and now it won't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 80

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char a_word[MAX_LEN];
    printf ("Enter some words:");
    scanf ("%s", a_word);
    printf ("The result is:" + a_word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *If this is too simple I will probably delete this post after it is answered.* Huh? Don't do that. *Especially* if your question is answered.

Comment: This isn't java ;-).

Comment: It is faster to find `printf` examples in Google than posting question here.

Comment: you can't delete the post now.It has 2 upvoted answers.you are now prone to downvotes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `scanf()`, the issue here is with `printf()` statement. In C, you need to have a format specifier to print the supplied arguments. Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) of `printf()` for further information.

In your code,

```
 printf ("The result is:" + a_word);
```

should be

```
printf ("The result is: %s \n" , a_word);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, you cannot append strings with `+`. To append strings, use `strcat()` or one of the other functions for this purpose. In your concrete example however, you can just do, as Sourav Ghosh already wrote do:

```
printf("The result is: %s \n" , a_word);
```